# Cannot find cygwin directories in Windows?

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin

I am using cygwin to learn BASH scripting inside windows. I created a directory /mystuff/unixstuff. I tried searching for this unixstuff directory in windows, but I cannot find it. Where does cygwin create files and folders ?

Comment: Are you sure you created `/mystuff/unixstuff`?  Did it give you errors?  I ask because you would normally not have permission to do this because of the leading `/`.  If you did successfully create it, cd to it in the bash shell then `cygpath -w $(pwd)` and this will give you the windows path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cygwin's root (`/`) directory is wherever you tell `setup.exe` to put it when you first install Cygwin.

I think the default is `C:\cgywin`. I've also used `D:\cygwin`.

You can use the `cygpath` command from the Cygwin bash shell to tell you. I'm not on my Cygwin system at the moment, but I think `cygpath -w /` will show you the Windows path of the Cygwin root, and `cygpath -w /mystuff/unixstuff` should tell you the Windows path to your `/mystuff/unixstuff` directory.

BTW, the usual convention for Unix-like systems (including Cygwin) is to put your own files under your home directory. Putting things directly under the root, as you've done with your `/mystuff` directory, risks interfering with system files. (Your home directory is probably `/home/username`, or in Windows something like `C:\cygwin\home\username`.)